# How are the HAL lock and unlock functions used and why?

Tags: c, stm32, i2c, hal

I'm trying to understand code which is written by another programmer. It used [I²C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) communication to write data on the EEPROM of an STM32 microcontroller.

Generally I understood how his code works, but I can't understand why he used the `HAL_LOCK` and `HAL_UNLOCK` functions.

These is the code of these methods:

```
typedef enum
{
    HAL_UNLOCKED = 0x00U,
    HAL_LOCKED   = 0x01U
} HAL_LockTypeDef;


#if (USE_RTOS == 1)

    /* Reserved for future use */
    #error "USE_RTOS should be 0 in the current HAL release"

#else

  #define __HAL_LOCK(__HANDLE__)                 \
      do{                                        \
          if((__HANDLE__)->Lock == HAL_LOCKED)   \
          {                                      \
             return HAL_BUSY;                    \
          }                                      \
          else                                   \
          {                                      \
             (__HANDLE__)->Lock = HAL_LOCKED;    \
          }                                      \
      } while (0)


  #define __HAL_UNLOCK(__HANDLE__)              \
      do{                                       \
          (__HANDLE__)->Lock = HAL_UNLOCKED;    \
      } while (0)
```

In which cases can these methods be used?

Comment: This is intended to be a nonrecursive, advisory mutex, but it's so catastrophically buggy that I believe you are better off not using it at all.  If you do not know what a "nonrecursive mutex" or an "advisory lock" is, please look those terms up.

Comment: Niiiiiiiiice use of the `return` statement inside that non-atomic macro. :) Tl;dr, no, there are no cases in which these macros can be used.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Someone was *trying* to implement a basic, advisory, non-recursive [mutex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)) with these macros (sometimes called a "lock" or "critical section", but those terms have other meanings; "mutex" is unambiguous). The idea is that you write code like this:

```
int frob_handle(handle_t hdl)
{
    __HAL_LOCK(hdl);
    hdl->frob_counter += 1;
    __HAL_UNLOCK(hdl);
    return 0;
}
```

And then only one thread of execution at a time can execute the statement `hdl->frob_counter += 1`. (In a real program, there would probably be quite a bit more code in there.) It's "advisory" because nothing stops you from forgetting to use the mutex when it's needed, and it's "non-recursive" because you can't call `__HAL_LOCK` a second time if you already have it locked. These are both relatively normal properties for a mutex to have.

In comments on the question, I said that these macros are "catastrophically buggy" and "I believe you are better off not using them at all." The most important problem is that `__HAL_LOCK` is not [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability).

```c
// This code is incorrect.
if ((__HANDLE__)->Lock == HAL_LOCKED)
  return HAL_BUSY;
else
  (__HANDLE__)->Lock = HAL_LOCKED;
```

Imagine that two threads of execution are trying to acquire the lock at the exact same time. They will both fetch `__HANDLE__->Lock` from memory at the same time, so they will both observe its value to be `HAL_UNLOCKED`, and they will both go on to the code that was supposed only to be executed by one thread at a time.  It's maybe easier to see the problem if I write out the assembly language that might be generated:

```asm
    ; This code is incorrect.
    ; r1 contains the __HANDLE__ pointer
    load.b  r0, Lock(r1)
    test.b  r0
    bnz     .already_locked
    inc.b   r0
    store.b Lock(r1), r0
    ...
.already_locked:
    mov.b   r0, #HAL_BUSY
    ret
```

There's nothing that would prevent both threads from executing the load instruction simultaneously, and thus both observing the mutex to be unlocked.  Even if there's only one CPU, an interrupt could fire while thread 1 is in between the load and the store, causing a context switch and allowing thread 2 to execute the load before thread 1 can execute the store.

For the mutex to do its job, you must somehow ensure that it is *impossible* for two concurrent threads both to load `HAL_UNLOCKED` from `__HANDLE__->Lock`, and this cannot be done with ordinary C. In fact, it can't be done with ordinary machine language; you need to use special instructions, such as [compare-and-swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap).

If your compiler implements [C2011](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)), then you can get at those special instructions using the new feature of [atomic types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic), but I don't know how to do it off the top of my head, and I'm not going to write out something that might be wrong. Otherwise, you need to use either compiler extensions or hand-written assembly.

A second problem is that `__HAL_LOCK` doesn't implement the operation that is usually called "lock". "Lock" is supposed to *wait* if it can't acquire the lock immediately, but what `__HAL_LOCK` does is *fail*. That operation's name is "try-lock", and the macro should be named accordingly. Also, macros that may cause the calling function to return are considered bad practice.

Comment: Your answer is complete and very clear! I don't understand why he use these methods but now i have more posibilities to achieve that . Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: If you do not understand why it might be necessary to _use_ a mutex in a particular context, please post a new question in which you show us the code that uses the mutex, and then try to explain to us why you think it wouldn't matter if two or more threads of execution ran that code simultaneously.

Comment: Good answer. I think it is possible to implement a mutex in ordinary C on simple hardware (one CPU, no memory access re-ordering) with this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson%27s_algorithm.

Comment: @odougs Yes, but only if you also have the ability to disable interrupts.

Comment: @zwol but can't someone just issue an atomic "interrupt disable" before the non atomic lock instruction and re enabling it after the lock was checked?

Comment: @thexeno That works only when you have the ability to execute that instruction (it's usually privileged) and also only when the CPU supports only one thread of execution ("uniprocessor").

Comment: thanks. I wanted to specify because the OP was referring to an STM32 MCU, for which normally you have these options, so that made me puzzled on why not use them.

Comment: Well, the code OP posted doesn't use those options, and disabling interrupts is also something you can't do with ordinary C or ordinary machine code either. But there *are* reasons to use atomic machine instructions (like compare and swap) instead of disabling interrupts: the code works unmodified if moved to a multiprocessor, it can be more efficient overall (especially if latency spikes are a concern), and you don't need to be in supervisor mode. Having said all that, I have never worked with the STM32 and I don't know what is best for that environment.