# STM HAL with FreeRTOS, yes/no/maybe?

Tags: stm32, microcontroller, freertos

I am struggling for a while to get my program running stable. I am experiencing hard faults while my program is running. I am going in circles.

My project:

- Nucleo F446ze (STM32F446ze)
- An LTE modem connected to uart2
- My PC connected to uart3 (for logging only).
- FreeRTOS downloaded from git, using their STM port
- LWIP 2.1.0 download from git

Some freertos configs

- configASSERT enabled in free rtos
- configCHECK_FOR_STACK_OVERFLOW set to 2
- configUSE_MALLOC_FAILED_HOOK set to 1
- configTOTAL_HEAP_SIZE set to 30k (I have 10k left when I query remaining heap size)
- INCLUDE_uxTaskGetStackHighWaterMark set to 1 (all tasks are within stack limits)
- SysTick is dedicated for FreeRTOS. I use TIM6 on 1khz to increase the HAL tick.
- All NVIC interrupts are set to 5 and higher, and again, configASSERT is enabled so pretty sure "interrupt management" is covered.

And using the defines to map free rtos interrupt handlers to CMSIS

```
#define vPortSVCHandler    SVC_Handler
#define xPortPendSVHandler PendSV_Handler
#define xPortSysTickHandler SysTick_Handler
```

My program does the following in sequence:

- setup clocks and peripherals
- enable interrupts
- create "StartLwIP" task
- start FreeRTOS scheduler

Then "StartLwIP" does:

- Send commands via uart2 to LTE modem to enable data mode
- Initialize LwIP stack (negotiate ppp with peer)
- Start a new "Test" task

The "Test" task does:

- Open connection to a TCP server on the internet
- Send a message
- Close socket
- vTaskDelay [100|10|-]
- repeat

When I use vTaskDelay(100), the program can run without problems for hours (ran it over night, no issues).

When I use vTaskDelay(10), the program runs for a while (between 1 minute - 5 minutes). Then it will crash and hang up in hard fault handler.

When I remove the vTaskDelay (which would be the preferred solution), it will crash even faster. Again, it will vary, but somewhere within seconds to a minute.

I am 99% sure the problem is not heap / stack related. The high water marks and heap consumption look perfectly fine. Not even close to go outside heap / stack.

Memory management is LWIP is somewhat confusing to me, but since I am *only* constantly opening and closing connections I can't believe I am running out of PBUFs in LWIP. I extended the numbers anyway.

I am struggling for weeks, and eventually started to doubt the STM HAL. Then I stumbled upon the `__HAL_LOCK` in peripheral libraries (uart in my case). For example in `HAL_UART_Transmit_IT`

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size)
{
  /* Check that a Tx process is not already ongoing */
  if (huart->gState == HAL_UART_STATE_READY)
  {
    if ((pData == NULL) || (Size == 0U))
    {
      return HAL_ERROR;
    }

    /* Process Locked */
    __HAL_LOCK(huart);                         <<<<====== 

    huart->pTxBuffPtr = pData;
    huart->TxXferSize = Size;
    huart->TxXferCount = Size;

    huart->ErrorCode = HAL_UART_ERROR_NONE;
    huart->gState = HAL_UART_STATE_BUSY_TX;

    /* Process Unlocked */
    __HAL_UNLOCK(huart);                       <<<<====== 

    /* Enable the UART Transmit data register empty Interrupt */
    __HAL_UART_ENABLE_IT(huart, UART_IT_TXE);

    return HAL_OK;
  }
  else
  {
    return HAL_BUSY;
  }
}
```

When I go to the definition of the lock macro I got a bit worried:

```
#if (USE_RTOS == 1U)
  /* Reserved for future use */
  #error "USE_RTOS should be 0 in the current HAL release"
#else
  #define __HAL_LOCK(__HANDLE__)                                           \
```

I've read several threads on this. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49132332/how-are-the-hal-lock-and-unlock-functions-used-and-why) and [here](https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X00009XkXUwSAN/freertos-and-hal) for example. I can also read many topics that the locking mechanism is poorly implemented and not thread safe at all. Interesting, since even without an RTOS, but using interrupts would then be a potential problem.

I downloaded STMCube latest version to check if this would be solved by now. But it's all still in the same state. STM HAL doesn't seem to do much with their USE_RTOS marco.

In my program, I am using different tasks that read and write over the same uart instance. The LWIP TCP thread will send data, while the LWIP RX thread will constantly read from uart. My uart receives data in interrupt mode (passing byte by byte to a ring buffer).

Finally my questions:

1. Is it possible that this locking mechanism is the root cause for my hard faults? I was trying to find somebody who experiences the same problem but couldn't find "proof" in that sense that would confirm this. So maybe the "horrible locking mechanism" isn't the best implementation, but is not the root cause for my problem.
2. Are there "steps" to take to get more details out of a hard fault? I would really like to find the offending line of code. I found [this](https://www.freertos.org/Debugging-Hard-Faults-On-Cortex-M-Microcontrollers.html) page that explains how to continue, but I don't know how to obtain the pc (I am using VScode, I can break in the while(1) loop, but then what...?).

It always crashes here:

[image]

```
HardFault_Handler
prvPortStartFirstTask
xPortStartScheduler
```

Sorry for the lengthy question, but I wanted to be thorough at least and hope that somebody can confirm some things, or maybe even help me in the right direction to get past this....

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you already find this post https://community.st.com/s/question/0D50X0000BOtfhnSQB/how-to-make-ethernet-and-lwip-working-on-stm32 ?

Comment: Oh my... I have now. I am going to read this carefully. Already found one explanation of issues I was experiencing. Lwip stops consuming packets as a result of the locking mechanism which is not thread safe. The issue is explained for ethernet, I assume the same applies for my pppos setup for uart peripheral locking. Thx for this link!

Answer (score 5):

There are three common reasons for the HF when switching the task:

1. Use of non ISR functions in ISR.
2. Stack overflow (enable stack overflow checks in the freeRTOS config)
3. Wrong interrupt priorities
   All three are very well explained in freeRTOS documentation.

I personally prefer to do the initializations in the tasks when the scheduler is started. It prevents many very difficult to track problems with code.

I use freeRTOS running with HAL, LWIP, different types of network connections without any problems.

Comment: Thx for the answer. 1) I only have 2 interrupts enabled, uart receive interrupt (prio=6) and timer6 (to increase hal tick, prio = 15). Only the uart interrupt calls into freertos (`xSemaphoreGiveFromISR`). 2) For the stackoverflow, I wrote a function that disables all interrupt and hangs up in while loop of highwatermark is close to zero (so it should go off even earlier, so that I don't risk that stack does overflow and I look at follow up damage). For the interrupt priorities I reread the docs so often, I did everything by the book.

Comment: I haven't tried the suggestion on freertos to "how to analyze hard faults". I guess I will have to dive into that. Read the PC counter and try to map that with bin/elf file. It's pretty rough to get through this. I have nobody to discuss stuff with other than you atm :D. So not expecting you will free up your agenda of course, but if you can think of anything else or have some brilliant insights that would help me get further it would be greatly appreciated. I am perfectly fine in sharing my code if you would be able to have a glance at it. It's 99% library code so "my code" isn't much anyway

Comment: By the, I am able to run my "tcp test" (open socket, close socket, repeat forever) over night without any problems, **as long as I add a vTaskDelay(100)" in the loop. Also capturing wireshark data on server side is flawless. No retransmissions or anything. When I remove the vTaskDelay(100) in the while loop, I will get a hard fault after roughly 5-30 seconds. That kind of rules out stack overflow for me.

Answer (score 2):

As I could have guessed, the problem was in my own code. I was using std::vector and I think I suffered from heap fragmentation because of the mallocs done by vector.

This page helped me a lot troubleshooting hard faults!

https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/cortex-m-fault-debug